# Guice @Nullable annotation

Tags: java, nullable, guice

In my service, I have a protected constructor with `@Inject` and one of the parameters (provider) `@Nullable`. Any ideas why I am getting

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
1) No implementation for [[service]] was bound.
```

? Guice is 3.0pre1, `@Nullable` is ours.

Comment: @Nullable is not enforced in any way, it's a note to the reader or code analysis tools. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076296/nullable-annotation-usage

Comment: @DavidGladfelter actually Guice does mind `@Nullable` https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@Nullable` isn't the same as `@Inject(optional=true)`... I think if you want to inject `null`, you need to `bind(Service.class).toProvider(Providers.<Service>of(null))` or to otherwise have some kind of provider bound that may return `null`.