# @Nullable annotation usage

Tags: java, annotations

I saw some method in java declared as:

```
void foo(@Nullable Object obj)
{ ... }
```

What's the meaning of `@Nullable` here? Does it mean the input could be `null`?

Without the annotation, the input can still be null, so I guess that's not just it?

Comment: From the answers below, I've learned that the annotation indicates null values are acceptable, examples of where it is used, code analyzers I can try out and that interpretations may vary. See why this format is a good one? +1s all round, especially for asking this question.

Comment: Which library is providing `@Nullable` in the context of your question? Is it [Checker?](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300

Answer (score 453, accepted):

It makes it clear that the method accepts null values, and that if you override the method, you should also accept null values.

It also serves as a hint for code analyzers like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/). For example, if such a method dereferences its argument without checking for null first, FindBugs will emit a warning.

Answer (score 96):

This annotation is commonly used to eliminate `NullPointerExceptions`. `@Nullable` says that this parameter might be `null`. A good example of such behaviour can be found in [Google Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable). In this lightweight dependency injection framework you can tell that this dependency might be `null`. If you would try to pass `null` without an annotation the framework would refuse to do it's job.

What is more, `@Nullable` might be used with `@NotNull` annotation. Here you can [find](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html) some tips on how to use them properly. Code inspection in IntelliJ checks the annotations and helps to debug the code.

Answer (score 20):

Different tools may interpret the meaning of `@Nullable` differently. For example, the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) and [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) handle `@Nullable` [differently](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#findbugs-nullable).

Answer (score 8):

Granted, there are definitely different thinking, in my world, I cannot enforce "Never pass a null" because I am dealing with uncontrollable third parties like API callers, database records, former programmers etc... so I am paranoid and defensive in approaches. Since you are on Java8 or later there is a bit cleaner approach than an `if` block.

```
public String foo(@Nullable String mayBeNothing) {
   return Optional.ofNullable(mayBeNothing).orElse("Really Nothing");
}
```

You can also throw some exception in there by swapping `.orElse` to 
`orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Dont' send a null"))`.

If you don't want to use @Nullable, which adds nothing functionally, why not just name the parameter with `mayBe...` so your intention is clear.

Comment: Using Optional as a replacement of `if` statement this is an anti-pattern, because it unnecessarily creates a new object.

Creator of Optional mentions this here:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ej0sss6cq14?start=1664&end=1800