# I don't understand this NullPointerException

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
RoomCell r = b.GetRoomCellAt(1, 2);
assertTrue(r.isDoorway());
```

The second line is failing with a null pointer exception, as if r hadn't been instantiated. But I'm setting it equal to a cell that that method retrieves, so it is obviously not null.

Why would I possibly be getting this error?

Comment: As you said, because `r` **is `null`**.

Comment: b.GetRoomCellAt(1, 2) must return null. Check the method docs o source...

Comment: because `b.GetRoomCellAt(1, 2);` is returning null

Comment: Or because some field inside `r.isDoorway` is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

What's your full stacktrace? It is needed in order to determine which of the following is the cause:

It's possible that GetRoomCellAt doesn't find a value and returns null

It's possible that the implementation of GetRoomCellAt accesses a null pointer

It's possible that the implementation of isDoorway accesses a null pointer

FYI, it is good practice to use the @Nullable annotation to annotate parameters and return types

Comment: +1 for making me read about the `@Nullable` annotation. A quick Google search led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076296/nullable-annotation-usage :)

Comment: If you use Eclipse, you now get built in Nullability analysis (though you may have to turn it on). That being said, I often find Guava's Optional to be more effective.

Answer (score 2):

The function `GetRoomCellAt()` can probably still return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(r != null)
{
  assertTrue(r.isDoorway());
}
```

instead of

```
assertTrue(r.isDoorway());


b.GetRoomCellAt(1, 2);
```

This cell may be null. So only you are getting `nullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

The only way you'd be getting a `NullPointerException` is if `r` was indeed `null`.  You can put this in your test conditions to ensure that, if `r` actually *is* `null`, then the test will fail:

```
RoomCell r = b.GetRoomCellAt(1, 2);
assertNotNull(r);
assertTrue(r.isDoorway());
```

If `r` is `null`, then the test fails early, and you avoid the NPE.