# In which cases I should use @Nullable annotation?

Tags: java, eclipse, guava, nullable

I investigate guava library for java.

reading different materials I faced with @Nullable annotation.

I added guava jar file to classpath but my IDE(eclipse) say:

> Nullable cannot be resolved to a type

But if I ctrl + click on Nullable I see blue underline and see next after:

> source not found

maybe it is problem with eclipse -  I don't know and this annotation located in another location.

But additionally I cannot understand situation when I should to use this annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in here.

```
javax.annotation.Nullable
```

I think you need this jar: jsr305.jar.

See also:

https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305

http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/package-tree.html

Regarding when you should use it - check this link.

[@Nullable annotation usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076296/nullable-annotation-usage)

Comment: usage is clearly now - thanks.

Comment: But I cannot understand why my IDE doesn't see this annotation. I need add something to classpath?

Comment: I upvoted it for the good link

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, I think you need jsr305.jar on your classpath, as I mentioned.

Comment: Use maven for dependency management. It's quite easy today with Eclipse. It'll take care of all transitive dependencies and you won't have to copy any jars anywhere.