# @Nullable over Spring's RestTemplate's PostForObject method

Tags: spring, resttemplate

What does this Annotation @Nullable over [postForObject](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.net.URI-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-)'s method mean in RestTemplate?

I want to clarify if the custom object I am getting can ever be null?

```
HttpEntity<CustResponse > request = new HttpEntity<>(custRequest, headers);
CustResponse custResponse = restTemplate.postForObject("url", request, CustResponse .class);
```

Can custResponse ever be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this annotation is used to avoid any auto generated warnings from code analyzer like [Find Bugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/). 
Similar question was posted here [@Nullable annotation usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076296/nullable-annotation-usage)